# How does MIG autoscale when autoscale policy is set to Target HTTP load balancing utilization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm learning load balancer and managed instance group auto scaling. I do not understand how does MIG autoscales when using HTTP load balancing utilization:

So, in MIG autoscale setting, I set Target HTTP load balancing utilization to 10%:

[image]

And in setting external HTTP load balancer: I have following two options:

utilization:

[image]

rate:

[image]

I can understand CPU based MIG autoscale, if the average CPU usage is greater than the number I inputed, then MIG will add more VMs to lower the number. It's very simple and straightforward.

But I do not know when will MIG autoscale when using HTTP load balancing utilization?

Comment: did you ever figure out how this works?

Answer (score 0):

[GCP Load Balancing offers three types of autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler#policies):

> **You can choose to scale using the following policies:**
>
> - Average CPU utilization.
> - HTTP load balancing serving capacity, which can be based on either utilization or requests per second.
> - Cloud Monitoring metrics (not supported by regional autoscalers)

First one as you said yourself is pretty self-explanatory.

And this is what the official documentaiton says about [Requests per second (RPS) based autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-load-balancing#scaling_based_on_https_load_balancing_serving_capacity):

> With `RATE`, you must specify a target number of requests per second on
> a per-instance basis or a per-group basis. (Only zonal instance groups
> support specifying a maximum rate for the whole group.

But there is a [limitation to the RPS based autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-load-balancing#applicable_load_balancing_configurations):

> Autoscaling does not work with maximum requests per group because this
> setting is independent of the number of instances in the instance
> group. The load balancer continuously sends the maximum number of
> requests per group to the instance group, regardless of how many
> instances are in the group.
>
> For example, if you set the backend to handle 100 maximum requests per
> group per second, the load balancer sends 100 requests per second to
> the group, whether the group has two instances or 100 instances.
> Because this value cannot be adjusted, autoscaling does not work with
> a load balancing configuration that uses the maximum number of
> requests per second per group.

You may also find useful to have a look at the types of  [GCP load balancing supported by in various scenarios](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#change_balancing_mode).

This document also describes [when it's best not to use some types of load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#restrictions_and_guidance).